# Spring Security - ClassCastException with AuthorizationFilter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm encountering a `ClassCastException` related to `AuthorizationFilter` when starting my Spring Boot application. The error message mentions that `org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter` cannot be cast to `javax.servlet.Filter`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter cannot be cast to class javax.servlet.Filter (org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter and javax.servlet.Filter are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer.configure(AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer.java:73) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer.configure(AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer.java:46) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.configure(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:349) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:303) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:38) ~[spring-security-config-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$SecurityFilterChainConfiguration.defaultSecurityFilterChain(SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration.java:61) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

**My dependencies:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>

        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>1-project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>1-project</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>




    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.04</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I thought that maybe it was some compatibility issues with spring 3.1.2

Comment: can you please attach your filter class in issue description ?

Comment: I think you have a Problem with Servlet-API Version. spring boot 3.1.2 uses servlet-api 6.0. And sevlet-api 6.0 doesnt content javax.servlet.Filter, but jakarta.servlet.Filter.

Comment: Wladimir Diskowski ,you are right ,thanks